# find next() not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a html form of as follow.

```
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">How many car?</label>
        <select class="form-control car_no" name="number_of_car" data-amount="<?php $ad = $prices->totalAmount; echo $ad; ?>">
            <option value="" selected>select car numbers</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Method to pay?</label>
        <select class="form-control ad_tt" name="payment_method">
            <option value="">Select Type</option>
            <option value="1">Full Payment</option>
            <option value="2">Advance Payment</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Paying amount</label>
        <div class="total_payment"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the value of class total_payment to something like '12345' when i change the option of class car_no. 
Here is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".car_no").change(function() {
        $(this).closest('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').find('.total_payment:first').innerHTML = '12345';
    });
});
```

Its not working. How could i do that.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').find('.total_payment').html('12345')`

Comment: still not working @satpal

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".car_no").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.slide_content.col-md-3').siblings().find('.total_payment').html("12345");
  });
});
```

Find the closest parent of clicked element, find `total_payment` in its siblings.

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why* (before hitting post, not as a ninja edit after).

Comment: Its not working. I cannot see text inside my div section

Comment: @void , If i want to change car_no to ad_tt, how could i get data of car_no.  Here is my sample code but its not working `$(".ad_tt").change(function(){

                var payment_type = $(this).val();

                var a = $(this).closest('.slide_content').parent().next().next().find(".car_no" ).val(); alert(a);
               

            });`

Comment: I didn't get you. You should post it as another question. And if this solves your OP then please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Never mind, I made it working. Yes, I have voted your answer @void

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".car_no").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.slide_content').siblings().find('.total_payment:first').text('12345');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">How many car?</label>
    <select class="form-control car_no" name="number_of_car" data-amount="<?php $ad = $prices->totalAmount; echo $ad; ?>">
      <option value="" selected>select car numbers</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Method to pay?</label>
    <select class="form-control ad_tt" name="payment_method">
      <option value="">Select Type</option>
      <option value="1">Full Payment</option>
      <option value="2">Advance Payment</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Paying amount</label>
    <div class="total_payment"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this way. Get the parent of the select that is the sibling of the div you want to out put then use `.siblings()`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write lump code when you can do it in a simple way? Since your code structure is simple you can follow this way:

Assign a ID to the `<label>`.

```
<label id='amount' for="">Paying amount</label>
```

When `<select>` is changed, update the label by referencing it's ID.

```
$(".car_no").change(function() {
$('label#amount').html("12345");
}
```

Comment: I cannot assign ID @Viswalinga, Its inside looped statement. I need to do using class.

Comment: You can easily assign ID to `label`, even if it is inside loop. Say if you are using `for` loop, `echo "<label id='amount-$i'><label>";` where `$i ` is the variable you use in for iteration. You can also add this reference to your `<select>` similary.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `next('selector')`, the target selector should be a sibling of the current element. 
In your case `.next('.slide_content')` is not a direct sibling of the select tag. So what you can do you can first call the `parent()` until the target sibling level of select tag and then do `next()`.

This works:

```
$(this).parents('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').find('.total_payment:first').html('asdfa');
```

and one two more thing, innerHTML is a javascript function cannot be used with jquery.